# Button is not clickable if we move to upside

Tags: html, css

If we visit [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/colored-marble-micromax-canvas-knight-a350-phone-case.html) , search for text "Save" using CTRL + F, you can see **"Save Design" button is clickable**.

[image]

We want to move the button to **upside**, so when we increase value to "bottom:117px;" , then **button is not clickable**

[image]

```
#aitcg-control-panel .apply-but {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 0;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 77px; /* or bottom:117px; or   top: -146px; */
    left: 400px;
}
```

Comment: please also post html

Comment: Well, you have created new profile? coz m seeing another user with same link. Try to ask with older one so it won't create spam on site. Hope you will understand

Comment: @Leothelion Thanks that you remember the link, yes my team member also having profile here, as he is working on other things, i am handling css part now. I hope you trust me.

Comment: Well m not blaming you..we are here to help so don't worry. :)

Comment: @Leothelion Thanks a lot for that, we are really greatfull to you that you helped us before lot of times....

Comment: @cssbeginner plz thank you for SO..and all others too.. my pleasure :)

Comment: @Leothelion sure, mainly for that wonderfull man who created this site :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment or delete all your **CSS** of this selector *`#aitcg-control-panel .apply-but`* and use this **CSS** fix as:

```
#aitcg-control-panel {
    position: absolute;
    right: 110px;
    bottom: 143px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.product-essential {
    position: relative;
}
```

this will solve your issue.

As instead of moving the *child* element, moving the *parent* element in your case will be a more wise decision for future debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Because other elements are not using absolute position property and overlapping this button.

Use `z-index`

```
#aitcg-control-panel .apply-but {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 0;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 177px;
    left: 400px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

This will bring this button to front.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because your div with class `.product-shop` has big width so is over the button. you can change its width using this code and the make `margin-top:-50px` to button.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1824px)
    .product-view .product-shop {
        width: 25%;
}
```

Or change button z-index

```
#aitcg-control-panel {
    z-index: 2;
```